# Does a smooth mapping always have an inverse map which is also smooth?

Tags: manifolds, inverse

If not, can someone provide counterexamples? Thank you

Comment: What goes wrong in the listed answers is that the derivative of the original functions vanishes in the given points. The [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) tells you that if that's never the case, your inverse will be smooth (when it exists).

Comment: @fuglede: The second sentence is only true for functions $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, given the question is tagged "manifolds" this is maybe not the most helpful thing (although given the other questions that OP has tagged "manifolds", maybe it is). The linked page gives an explicit example of a noninvertible $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ function with never-zero derivative. This is possible because the inverse function theorem only gets you invertibility in a neighborhood of a point, and even if you get an inverse for every point, the inverses may not play well together.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, not every smooth map is invertible as it may not be a bijection. Secondly, even if it is invertible, its inverse may not be smooth. Consider the map $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x^3$. This is a smooth map which is also a bijection, so it has an inverse, namely $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$. Note that $f^{-1}$ is not differentiable at $0$ so it certainly isn't smooth.

Answer (score 4):

$f(x) = x^3$ is a counterexample.